# How I replace multiple chars with only one char in a simple way?

Tags: java, replace, char

I want to replace some chars with accents in a String like this example:

```
str.replace('á','a');
str.replace('â','a');
str.replace('ã','a');
```

This will work, but I want to know if there is some simple way where I pass all the chars to be replaced and the char that will replace they.
Something like these:

```
replace(str,"áâã",'a');
```

or:

```
char[] chars = {'á','â','ã'};
replace(str,chars,'a');
```

I looked at `StringUtils` from `Apache Lang`, but not exists this way I mentioned.

Comment: A regular expression is likely the simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to look at

```
str.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
```

Off the top of my head, I can't recall Java's regex format, so I can't give you a format that catches those three. In my mind, it would be

```
'[áâã]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29): str.replaceAll('[áâã]', 'a');

Answer (score 0):

This should work str.replaceAll("[áâã]",'a')

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replaceChars("áâã", "aaa");
```

Comment: replaceChars? From where is this?

Comment: [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html); it's what the OP says he's using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple `originalString.replaceAll("á|â|ã", "a")` will do

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replaceAll("[áâã]","a");
```

Try this - it's a regex patter saying replace occurrence of each of the characters by "a"